# Unable to send email using expressjs and nodejs

Tags: node.js, email, express, nodemailer

I have to send an email on the submit button in a website using expressjs and nodejs but I am unable to send email on the post call as I am getting following error on console.I am using nodemailer to send the email here.

Error:--

```
 [Error: connect ECONNREFUSED]
 code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
 errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
 syscall: 'connect' }
```

and following is code:--

```
var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
var ctrl={
    post:function(req,res)
    {
        console.log('If this function returns promise it would be handled accordingly.'+req.body.Name);
                // create reusable transporter object using SMTP transport
        var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
        service: 'smtp.gmail.com',
        auth: {
        user: 'example@e20.in',
        pass: 'password'
        },

    });

// setup e-mail data with unicode symbols
    var mailOptions = {
        from: 'example@e20.in', // sender address
        to: 'example@e20.in', // list of receivers
        subject: 'Hello', // Subject line
        text: 'Hello world', // plaintext body
        html: '<b>Hello world</b>', // html body
        replyTo:req.body.Email
    };

// send mail with defined transport object
    transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, info){
     if(error){
        console.log(error);
     }else{
        console.log('Message sent: ' + info.response);
     }
    });
    return {Name:req.body.Name}; //req.body form post
        //return {Name:req.query.Name}; //req.query url querystring
    },
    put:function(req,res){
        return {};
    }
}

module.exports = ctrl;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use an XOAuth2 token to connect to Gmail. No worries, Nodemailer already knows about that:

```
var smtpTransport = nodemailer.createTransport('SMTP', {
  service: 'Gmail',
  auth: {
    XOAuth2: {
      user: smtpConfig.user,
      clientId: smtpConfig.client_id,
      clientSecret: smtpConfig.client_secret,
      refreshToken: smtpConfig.refresh_token,
      accessToken: smtpConfig.access_token,
      timeout: smtpConfig.access_timeout - Date.now()
   }
  }
};
```

check this [link](https://github.com/andris9/nodemailer-smtp-transport) for nodemailer SMTP. It will help in clarification